# How to go back to previous instance

Tags: android

I have converted my blog into Android app by using web view but when I click back button on mobile my app gets closed. please help . I have just started learning how to code an Android app

Answer (score 0):

If you use your WebView in activity the most simple way i guess is to override `onBackPressed()` method:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {  
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```